# Is there a commercially available inertial gyro with electronic control?

Tags: control, gyroscope

Searching for electronic gyros doesn't turn up what I am after. Rather than an instrument to measure rotation, what I want is a device that I can mount in a flying machine, where I can apply a certain moment in order to have the flying machine react with the opposite moment in order to control attitude.  A classic physical gyroscope behaves like this, but I am unsure if there are any available with electronic controls.

**Is there a name for such devices**, that I can Google for?

To clarify, this isn't asking for a product recommendation, just want to know if such a thing exists and what it would be called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The device you describe is known as a Control Moment Gyroscope (CMG).  These devices are mostly used for attitude control in *spacecraft*, but are also commercially available.